# Laravel Query Builder - Where date is now using carbon

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

How to get only date on database column, I have difficulties using Carbon on controller:

```
$data['nowUser'] = User::where('date', Carbon::today()->toDateString())->get();
```

Date column looks like this in the database:

[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

That is a `DATETIME` column, so there's no need for additional formatting the `Carbon` instance. However you need to use `whereDate` if you want the fetch all users for which the `date` column contains today's date:

```php
$data['nowUser'] = User::whereDate('date', '=', Carbon::today())->get();
```

Because when you pass `Carbon::today()` to the Query Builder method, the [`__toString`](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon/blob/master/src/Carbon/Carbon.php#L1067-L1070) method will be automatically called and return a `DATETIME` string with the format from [`Carbon::DEFAULT_TO_STRING_FORMAT`](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon/blob/master/src/Carbon/Carbon.php#L117), which is exactly that MySQL format `Y-m-d H:i:s`.